# API Token Authentication method

Tags: api, authentication, token

I am trying to build an API service that will communicate with another application but I have some concerns about the security of the application. I want it to use token authentication but in all tutorials that I read is said to give the user a hashed token and make requests with it. For example if I want to retrieve a user:

```
myapp.com/user/1?my_token=<TOKEN>
```

This token would be checked for example if it contains an existing user with username and password that has the access to this route. But no matter what checks I make on the server if someone knows this token he can send requests from anywhere.
I saw that in Google APIs developers should paste their API_KEY as a query variable but maybe they have some other security checks? Isn't it like putting your username and password as plain text in the query parameters? What is the best way to authenticate users without the possibility of man in the middle attack?